# Warning with GridSearchCV when using to train ANN

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I'm learning to build an ANN, but I got some error when I tried to tune the parameters using GridSearchCV:

```
 def build_classifier(optimizer):
            classifier = Sequential()
            # First layer
            classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, activation = "relu", 
                                 kernel_initializer = "uniform", input_dim = 13))
            #classifier.add(Dropout(rate = 0.1)) # randomly dropout some neurons
            # Second layer
            classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, activation = "relu", 
                                 kernel_initializer = "uniform"))
            #classifier.add(Dropout(rate = 0.1)) # randomly dropout some neurons
            # Last layer
            classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid", 
                                 kernel_initializer = "uniform"))
            classifier.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "BinaryCrossentropy", 
                              metrics = "accuracy")
            return classifier
            classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier)
        parameters = {"batch_size": [25, 32], "epochs": [100, 500], 
                      "optimizer": ["adam", "rmsprop"]}
        grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier, param_grid = parameters,
                                  scoring = "accuracy", cv = 10)
        grid_search = grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

So when I ran this:

```
parameters = {"batch_size": [25, 32], "epochs": [100, 500], 
              "optimizer": ["adam", "rmsprop"]}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier, param_grid = parameters,
                          scoring = "accuracy", cv = 10)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I met this warning:

```
D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py:455: UserWarning: `model.predict_classes()` is deprecated and will be removed after 2021-01-01. Please use instead:* `np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis=-1)`,   if your model does multi-class classification   (e.g. if it uses a `softmax` last-layer activation).* `(model.predict(x) > 0.5).astype("int32")`,   if your model does binary classification   (e.g. if it uses a `sigmoid` last-layer activation).
  warnings.warn('`model.predict_classes()` is deprecated and '
```

I have tried many ways to fix this, but it didn't work. I would be very appreciate if anyone could give any solution to this!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the warning `model.predict_classes()` is deprecated it will be removed in the new release. It recommended to use `model.predict(x)` instead. Take a look at the model predict api in detail [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential?version=nightly#predict).

This warning message does not stop from execution, still you can train model without any error. You can suppress the Warning by

```
import logging, os
logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"
import tensorflow as tf
```